# How to echo string to a file using vimscript?

Tags: echo

I want to use the `echo` command from vim (not the `shell` ones or the external command) for outputting some strings to external files.

I know I could use `redir` but I'm just wondering if there isn't a simpler way (in pure vimscript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:redir > file` or `:redir >> file` is indeed the way to redirect messages from `:echo` to an external file.

Another way to write to a file from Vimscript is to use the [`writefile()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#writefile%28%29) function, which takes a filename and typically a Vimscript list and writes the contents of the list to the external file, one item per line. See [`:help writefile()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#writefile%28%29) for more details.